# chart js download to png with canvas.toDataURL() not working in IE and firefox

Tags: javascript, canvas, chart.js

I am using canvas.toDataURL() to download chart.js chart ,it is perfectly working with chrome but not working with IE and Firefox.here is my code

```js
 var link = document.createElement('a');
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasId');
link.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
link.download = 'IMAGE.png';
link.click();
```

Thank you.

Comment: which version your  IE and Firefox

Comment: im using the latest version of both.

Comment: im able to get the png image in new window using this code "var windowtab=window.open('about:blank','image from canvas');
                    windowtab.document.write("<img src='"+href+"' alt='from canvas'/>");" but im unable to download the png image

Answer (score 0):

```js
 var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasId');
 if(canvas.msToBlob){
     var blob = canvas.msToBlob();
     window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, 'image.png');
 }
 else{
       var link = document.createElement('a');
       link.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
       link.download = 'IMAGE.png';
       document.body.append(link);
       link.click();
   }
```

The anchor tag you are creating also needs to be added to the DOM in Firefox and IE, in order to be recognized for click events.

Comment: thank you for your answer it worked for Firefox but not for IE11.

Comment: Edit for IE browser

Comment: @erdiyılmaz it is not working on IE11.. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox, you need to do the link.click (though you may not want to do that in Chrome as it results in a double download).  However, IE (except for the latest versions of Edge) doesn't support the "download" attribute on the a tag, and you need to save the canvas slightly differently.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasId');
var isIE = !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident/g) || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE/g);
if (!isIE) {
    let image = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);

    // we are getting the a tag to add the 'download' attribute and the file contents
    let downloadLink = document.getElementById("download");
    downloadLink.setAttribute("download", downloadFileName);
    downloadLink.setAttribute("href", image);

    // For some reason, we need to click the button again in firefox for the download to happen
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Firefox/g)) {
        downloadLink.click();
    }
}

if (isIE) {
    var blob = canvas.msToBlob();
    window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, downloadFileName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Chart.js API documentation there is a built in function called .toBase64Image() which you may wish to use instead, as you've outlined your file extension as being .png.

[image]

As Becky stated above, in Firefox, *link.click()* needs to be used in order for the file to download. However, the element we created (*link*) needs to be appended to the body of your HTML document in order for *link.click()* to function as required. It is important that once this statement has been executed, to **remove the link element** from your HTML document, so your HTML body doesn't accumulate these elements every time you try to download a chart. IE requires the canvas to be saved differently through the blob functions.

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvasId');
let chart_name = = new Chart(canvas, config);

var isIE = !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident/g) || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE/g);

if (!isIE) {

  // Create a hyperlink element.
  let link = document.createElement('a');

  // Set image URL and filename.
  link.href = chart_name.toBase64Image();
  link.download = 'IMAGE.png';

  // If browser is Firefox, the element we created above must be appended to the
  // body of the HTML document & therefore removed after.
  if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Firefox/g)) {
      document.body.append(link);  
      link.click();
      document.body.removeChild(link);
  }
}

if (isIE) {
  var blob = canvas.msToBlob();
  window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, 'IMAGE.png');
}
```